# assertDatabaseHas failing saying "Table is empty"

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I am trying to assert that database has a record but its failing and I have no idea how to resolve the issue

My code is:

```
class ControlTransferRejectTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;

    private const TO_USER_ID = 'to_user_id';
    private const FROM_USER_ID = 'from_user_id';
    private const TC_SITE_ID = 'tc_site_id';
    private const CONTROL_TYPE = 'type';
    private const ROUTE_STORE = 'controltransfers.store';

    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();

        // spin up 16 sites to support control transfer
        $this->sites = create('App\Site', [], 16);

        // spin up 107 users to support control transfer
        $this->users = create('App\User', [], 107);
    }

    /** @test */
    public function authenticated_user_with_pending_control_transfer_rejects()
    {
        // ARRANGE test preconditions
        $postArray = [
            self::TO_USER_ID => $this->users[0]->id,
            self::TC_SITE_ID => $this->sites[0]->id,
            self::CONTROL_TYPE => 'Transfer'
        ];

        $response = $this->post(route(self::ROUTE_STORE), $postArray);

        $this->assertDatabaseHas('control_transfers', [
            self::TO_USER_ID => $this->users[0]->id,
            parent::SITE_ID =>  $this->sites[0]->id,
            self::FROM_USER_ID => $this->users[1]->id,
            self::CONTROL_TYPE => 'Transfer',
            'outcome' => NULL,
            'pending' => True
        ]);


        // ACT on the items under test

        // ASSERT that the expected results have occurred

    }
}
```

But when I try to execute the test it says

> The table is empty
>   vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/Concerns/InteractsWithDatabase.php:22

My usecase is I am calling a controller function that creates record in two different tables.

I am trying to check for in one table but thats failing with above error.

Comment: When you check your database tables do you actually see the data in there? Or does it actually not get added to the database?

Comment: Am using laravel which uses sqllite,not sure if I can check data.

Comment: Yoiu can use something like https://sqlitebrowser.org/ to check your database.